# Tomcat 7 fails to load ojdbc6.jar no matter where I have it specified

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc, oracle11g, web-deployment-project

This is one really trying my patience.  I have a simple Spring 3.1 + Jersey application that I'm trying to work with ojdbc6.jar as my datasource.  Unfortunately, no matter what I try, it can never find "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" class.

I have turned on class loader tracing and I CAN SEE the ojdbc6.jar being loaded:

```
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.Wrapper from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.Connection from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriverExtension from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.DriverInfo from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver$1 from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.ClassRef$XMLTypeClassRef from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.DiagnosabilityMXBean from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDiagnosabilityMBean from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded javax.management.StandardMBean$MBeanInfoSafeAction from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSQLException from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLNonTransientException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLTransientException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLDataException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLTimeoutException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLClientInfoException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded java.sql.SQLRecoverableException from /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/classes.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping$Tokenizer from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.Message from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.Message11 from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.internal.ObjectDataFactory from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.sql.ORADataFactory from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.sql.AnyDataFactory from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.internal.ObjectData from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.sql.ORAData from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.sql.TypeDescriptorFactory from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleConnection from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.internal.ClientDataSupport from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.OracleConnectionWrapper from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
[Loaded oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection from file:/opt/tomcat7/lib/ojdbc6.jar]
```

But when I try my web service call, I get the following:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [oraclepoc] in context with path [/oraclepoc] threw exception
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:729)
    at com.company.sims.oraclepoc.dao.ProcessStatusDaoImpl.getStatusByProcessID(ProcessStatusDaoImpl.java:15)
    at com.company.sims.oraclepoc.resources.ProcessStatusRestController.getEMSStatusByProcessID_XML(ProcessStatusRestController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 47 more
Jan 18, 2013 11:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [oraclepoc] in context with path [/oraclepoc] threw exception
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:729)
    at com.company.sims.oraclepoc.dao.ProcessStatusDaoImpl.getStatusByProcessID(ProcessStatusDaoImpl.java:15)
    at com.company.sims.oraclepoc.resources.ProcessStatusRestController.getEMSStatusByProcessID_XML(ProcessStatusRestController.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver class '"oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1429)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1371)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
    ... 47 more
```

My application context XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.sims.oraclepoc"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" 
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location">
            <value>jdbc.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${jdbc.driver}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${jdbc.user}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="processStatusDao" class="com.company.sims.oraclepoc.dao.ProcessStatusDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>  
</beans>
```

My jdbc.properties file:

```
jdbc.driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
jdbc.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1522:db"/>
jdbc.user="USER"/>
jdbc.password="password"/>
```

I've tried putting it in the WEB-INF/lib directory and in within Tomcat's LIB directory.  Both attempts have been in failure.

Comment: And where is your ojdbc.jar? Are there multiple of them in your Tomcat (one in tomcat\lib and another in your WEB-INF\lib)?

Comment: At no point in time were there 2 of the same jars used.  I just wrote that to show where I did put the JAR file for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that after a good night's rest and some time away led me to [this link here in SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994642/tomcat-jdbc-mysql-classnotfoundexception?rq=1) Turns out my jdbc.properties file was badly constructed for my Oracle instance but right for my Sybase one.  Thanks to all for your help.  Down voting me for being absurd.

Answer (score 7):

I believe its a class-loading issue.
The things I can think of are:

- Two ojdbc.jars in accessible in your classpath, one in tomcat/lib, another in WEB-INF/lib
- Two ojdbc.jars in accessible in your classpath, one in JRE ext folder, another in WEB-INF/lib

or something like that.

Just be sure that there is just one JDBC driver in your classpath. You can remove the one in WEB-INF/lib to see whether your application works or not.

Comment: At no point in time were there 2 of the same jars used.  I just wrote that to show where I did put the JAR file for testing.  It failed in either or.

Comment: For my case, removing jar under WEB-INF/lib and moving under tomcat/lib solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

The `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` class was deprecated for years and was [removed from ojdbc6.jar in Oracle JDBC Drivers release 11.1.0.7.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/111070-readme-083278.html).

You should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead.

Comment: Tried and failed:  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
 at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:1420)
 ... 47 more`

Comment: Here's what I've done: I took the 11.2.0.2 JAR and checked it via 7zip.  Check out OK.  Looked at the file structure and it was all correct.  The classes are where they're supposed to be.  I wrote a small Java application OUTSIDE of this web application and it compiled just fine.  I used a completely DIFFERENT JAR (Sybase) to isolate my application and THAT JAR worked.  At this point, I went ahead and then used my ORACLE JAR file and it proceeded to fail.  I, then, downloaded 11.2.0.3 and performed the SAME steps and that too failed.

Comment: Oh, and then, I deployed the application to:  Glassfish 3+, Oracle WebLogic 11g and WebSphere 8.0.0.5 and they ALL failed with the SAME error.  Does that help?

Comment: I just downloaded and inspected Oracle JDBC Drivers Release 11.2.0.3.  This odbc6.jar had both oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.class (14,292 bytes, and a couple of related classes) and oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver.class (2,286).  Also look [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=339971)

Comment: I downloaded the same files that you used, same size and all.  I'm just perplexed that no matter where I put this OJDBC, my project can't find it.  Perhaps one of the other JARs in my web application is clobbering it?  All I'm using is Spring 3.1, Jersey, Common-dbcp and pool.  It's just so weird.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the .jar is in the correct place?  For example, in this case, it needed to be located i nTomcat "common/lib", instead of "app/lib":

- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?13965-oracle-JDBC-throws-error-while-initializing

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't read my information.  This is Tomcat 7 and if you understood that, you would know that the lib directory has been collapsed.  Please see `http://tomcat.apache.org/migration.html`.  That and the topic is from 2005 which would be convenient, if I was running Spring 1.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Jetbrains IntelliJ IDE. I selected *Settings – Build, Execution, Deployment – Build Tools – Maven – Runner* and selected a version higher than 1.6 of Java in JRE ComboBox. The error vanished.